# Why was my answer on why one can't I check-in online for international flights deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I wrote the answer below for [Why can't I check-in online for international flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/188070/1810) and it was deleted. Why?

---

> Why can't I check-in online for international flights?

Most often when flying to the US, it's because the airline wants to check if the passenger is allowed to enter the destination country.

> Why have an online check-in option if you can't use it?

Because they suck.

Comment: I cannot tell you directly, as I did not delete it, but I would also have deleted it had I seen it first as it fails to meet quality standards, and had 7 downvotes in a couple of hours for that reason. Please re-familiarise yourself with the site requirements on quality via the [about] and [answer] pages.

Comment: @RoryAlsop "Most often when flying to the US, it's because the airline wants to check if the passenger is allowed to enter the destination country." is a concise and correct answer to the question. What else shall I add?

Comment: I would suggest reading the other answers especially those with many upvotes. You'll see they give context, additional information and fully answer the question. You gave 2 sentences. And one of those was a zero value personal opinion that would have no place in an answer, as well you know.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Hilmar's and littleadv's answers say pretty much the same info with more words or add info not asked in the question. Also, "Because they suck." is not a zero value personal opinion, it means airlines could do it (not having an online check-in option if we can't use it), but they sometimes don't.

Comment: I also did not delete it but I completely agree with @RoryAlsop comments here. This was certainly below the standards we expect.

Comment: @Willeke Look at littleadv's answer. It is the same as my answer, with some extra info about automated kiosks that the OP didn't ask for (interesting to add, but not required by the question).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, the user you mention did not use the rude language, which you repeated here in your last line, that alone would be a reason to flag for many of our users. And however you react I am done with this meta question.

Comment: @Willeke I only meant "very bad" but I can change that word with another word, if that's considered rude. Any other issue with the answer?